# Is there a way to change the border of select drop down on keyboard tab select?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to figure out a way to change the border of select drop down menu on keyboard tab select. Can someone let me know if there's a way to do that?

I want the border to be changed just on focus (using keyboard tab) not on clicking...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if is that what you want http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/MV44w/

```
select:focus{
    border: 2px solid #0F0;
    outline: 2px solid #0F0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the styles of an element on focus (and blur) as follows:

HTML:

```
<select><option>a</option></select>
<br/>
<select><option>b</option></select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('select')
        .focus(function() {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red'); 
        })
        .blur(function() {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'black'); 
        });
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kg924/1/)

EDIT: updated the example to use select boxes.